# streams and llvm error

Tags: c, visual-studio, stream, llvm

Here is the code of the functions:

```
int getStream()
    {
           int fd = _dup(fileno(stdout));
           freopen("tmp","w",stdout);
           return fd;
    }


void freeStream(int fd)
{
       _dup2(fd,fileno(stdout));
       close(fd);
}
```

The code of main program:

```
printf(“start tets”);
int fd = getStream();
printf(“redirection”);
freeStream(fd);
```

This is a part of large program which uses llvm 
The problem I get after `freeStream(fd)`: `LLVM ERROR: IO failure on output stream.`
I understand that the problem is with freeStream implementation.
What do you think?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jason diagnosed, you need to `fflush()` the stream (`stdout`) before you close the underlying file (via the `_dup2()` call).

Another problem is that there is no error checking in the code; you don't know which, if any, of your function calls are failing.  At least while resolving this issue, you need to monitor both `freopen()` and `_dup2()` to ensure they work.

It is not clear that on Windows, you can reach behind the back of the `<stdio.h>` library and change the file descriptor.  On Unix, I think it would likely work - not necessarily supported, but probably it would work.  But I can easily imagine ways it fails on Windows (without being certain that my imagination is not simply being to vivid).

Ultimately, I am not convinced there's a portable way to reinstate `stdout` back to its original output after using `freopen()` on it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to reliably see the text `"redirection"` end up in your temporary file, you'll need to flush the buffer in `stdout` before you close it to get rid of any pending writes that are buffered in the stream.  To accomplish this, add this line to your `freeStream` function:

```
void freeStream(int fd)
{
   fflush(stdout); //<== add this line
   _dup2(fd,fileno(stdout));
   close(fd);
}
```